# MongoDB, mongod não executa no cmd

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cmd, windows-7

Estou tentando rodar o MongoDB 3.2 em uma Maquina Windows7 de 32bits, mas estou tendo dificuldades para rodar o comando `mongod` no cmd, quando utilizo o comando ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.021-0300 I CONTROL  [main]
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.029-0300 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't
> have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want
> durability. 2019-09-14T10:39:34.033-0300 I CONTROL  [main]
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.184-0300 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or
> later update is not insta lled, will zero-out data files
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.255-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
> starting : pid=4268 port=270 17 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 32-bit
> host=Fabricio-PC 2019-09-14T10:39:34.267-0300 I CONTROL
> [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vista/Windows S erver 2008
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.274-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
> v3.2.22 2019-09-14T10:39:34.292-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git
> version: 105acca0d443f9a47c1a5bd 608fd7133840a58dd
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.301-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
> tcmalloc 2019-09-14T10:39:34.318-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> modules: none 2019-09-14T10:39:34.331-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> build environment: 2019-09-14T10:39:34.337-0300 I CONTROL
> [initandlisten]     distarch: i386 2019-09-14T10:39:34.343-0300 I
> CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: i386
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.349-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
> 2019-09-14T10:39:34.358-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
> initAndListen: 28663 Ca nnot start server. The default storage engine
> 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please
> specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g.
> --storageEngine=mmapv1 ., terminating 2019-09-14T10:39:34.369-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

obs: Ja criei as pasta `data` e `db` no disco `C:\`;

oque posso fazer para consertar este erro?

Comment: Esse é o erro:  
 **The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build
of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1**   tente adicionar esse parâmetro na chamada do mongod: **--storageEngine=mmapv1**

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desinstale o MongoDB e exclua suas pastas após a instalação, pode usar o [RevoUninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/) para facilitar.

Siga estes passos:

1. Instale o MongoDB normalmente, aguarde até aparecer o Compass, se
   não aparecer, desinstale e instale novamente. Copie o caminho da
   instalação, vamos precisar.
2. Abra um prompt de comandos (cmd.exe) como administrador.
3. Digite: `cd C:\`
4. Depois: `md "\data\db"`
5. Depois: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="c:\data\db`
6. Dê um "CTRL+C" e feche o cmd.exe.
7. Copie o caminho da instalação até a pasta "bin": `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\SUA_VERSAO_DO_MONGODB\bin`
8. Exemplo: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
9. Vá nas propriedades do sistema e adicione às variáveis de ambiente do SISTEMA (pesquise no google), o caminho da instalação em “PATH”:
10. Clique duas vezes em PATH em "Variáveis de ambiente do sistema",
11. Depois em "Novo",
12. Cole o caminho que você copiou e aperte OK.

Para testar, abra um prompt de comandos (cmd.exe) e digite "mongo", se abrir o console do DB então está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Perfeito, tentei de tudo por 2 horas, essa resposta foi na lata.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário rodar o comando:

`mongod --journall --storageEngine=mmapv1`